# Slider inside the table header

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I designed html table and i need to slider inside the table header, the first td is fixed poxition. I attached the image please check it.Give me your thoughts and inputs. how to i manage? I added the what i have the html code and i attached image what i need to get output.
[image]

```
<table style="border:1px solid #ccc;margin-left: 0px;border-right-width: 1px;border-right-style: solid;border-right-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);" id="student-monitor-table-data" class="student-monitor-table-data tablesorter tablesorter-default">
   <thead>
      <tr class="tablesorter-headerRow">
         <th class="student-name common-sorting headcol tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerAsc headerSortUp" data-column="0" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" style="-moz-user-select: none;">Name</th>
         <th class="student-score common-sorting tablesorter-header" data-column="1" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" style="-moz-user-select: none;">Score</th>
         <th data-type="question" style="text-align: center; -moz-user-select: none;" data-column="2" class="tablesorter-header" tabindex="0" unselectable="on">
            <div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Question 1</div>
         </th>
         <th data-type="question" style="text-align: center; -moz-user-select: none;" data-column="3" class="tablesorter-header" tabindex="0" unselectable="on">
            <div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Question 2</div>
         </th>
         <th data-type="question" style="text-align: center; -moz-user-select: none;" data-column="4" class="tablesorter-header" tabindex="0" unselectable="on">
            <div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Question 3</div>
         </th>
         <th data-type="question" style="text-align: center; -moz-user-select: none;" data-column="5" class="tablesorter-header" tabindex="0" unselectable="on">
            <div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Question 4</div>
         </th>
         <th data-type="question" style="text-align: center; -moz-user-select: none;" data-column="6" class="tablesorter-header" tabindex="0" unselectable="on">
            <div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Question 5</div>
         </th>
         <th data-type="question" style="text-align: center; -moz-user-select: none;" data-column="7" class="tablesorter-header" tabindex="0" unselectable="on">
            <div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Question 6</div>
         </th>
         <th data-type="question" style="text-align: center; -moz-user-select: none;" data-column="8" class="tablesorter-header" tabindex="0" unselectable="on">
            <div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Question 7</div>
         </th>
         <th data-type="resource" style="text-align: center; -moz-user-select: none;" data-column="9" class="tablesorter-header" tabindex="0" unselectable="on">
            <div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Resource 8</div>
         </th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr data-index="1" user-score="84" class="odd">
         <td data-col-span="8" data-username="jennie" class="headcol">
            <div class="headcolUsername" style="margin-left:7%;">jennie</div>
         </td>
         <td style="text-align:center;">1%</td>
         <td >A
         </td>
         <td >A
         </td>
         <td >A
         </td>
         <td >A
         </td>
         <td >A
         </td>
         <td >A
         </td>
         <td >A
         </td>
         <td data-category="interactive">
            <div class="reaction-image reaction-mean1 monitor-collection "></div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-index="1" user-score="77" class="even">
          <td data-col-span="8" data-username="jennie" class="headcol">
            <div class="headcolUsername" style="margin-left:7%;">jennie</div>
         </td>
         <td style="text-align:center;">1%</td>
         <td >A
         </td>
         <td >A
         </td>
         <td >A
         </td>
         <td >A
         </td>
         <td >A
         </td>
         <td >A
         </td>
         <td >A
         </td>
         <td data-category="interactive">
            <div class="reaction-image reaction-mean1 monitor-collection "></div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-index="1" user-score="35" class="odd">
         <td data-col-span="8" data-username="jennie" class="headcol">
            <div class="headcolUsername" style="margin-left:7%;">jennie</div>
         </td>
         <td style="text-align:center;">1%</td>
         <td >A
         </td>
         <td >A
         </td>
         <td >A
         </td>
         <td >A
         </td>
         <td >A
         </td>
         <td >A
         </td>
         <td >A
         </td>
         <td data-category="interactive">
            <div class="reaction-image reaction-mean1 monitor-collection "></div>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you share your code, show what you have tried to do?

Comment: Rather than posting a screenshot, post some actual code and maybe even link it to a jsfiddle to show how it's currently working.

Comment: I designed only table design, still i didnot implement the slider. before i start to work i need clarifications.

Comment: @RSKMR share whatever you currently have. Are we supposed to create everything from scratch by ourselves to diagnose the problem at hand..?

Comment: To clarify, I recommend you to use css and javascript. Calculate the visible width of the _resources_ row and fix a width to each _resource_ `td`. Then you have enough to calculate animate (or just css) movements

Comment: I added code what i have now.